# Draw linear gradient at a certain angle

Tags: 2d, cairo, pixman

I'm trying to draw linear gradients with libpixman using the `pixman_image_create_linear_gradient()` function. It works fine for drawing gradients that run from left to right and from top to bottom but I don't see how I can draw gradients at a specific angle (0-360 degrees) like they're possible in CSS. For example, a linear gradient that is rotated by 45 degrees.

I think one has to use the arguments `p1` and `p2` for this because they define the gradient direction but there is no documentation at all and I can't really figure out how to use these two parameters to rotate the gradient.

For vertical gradients I simply set them to

```
p1.x = 0; p1.y = 0;
p2.x = 0; p2.y = height - 1;
```

And for horizontal gradients I use

```
p1.x = 0; p1.y = 0;
p2.x = width - 1; p2.y = 0;
```

But which values should I use for arbitrary rotation? Simply applying a 2D rotation matrix to the points doesn't look right, e.g. when drawing a gradient that is 640x480 and rotating this by 45 degrees I end up with the points

```
p1.x = 81; p1.y = 560;
p2.x = 559; p2.y = 559;
```

which draws the gradient in the right direction but there are about 80 pixels of blank space on either side of the gradient so I must be doing something wrong.

Could anybody tell me how to get this right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *guess* that Pixman implements linear gradients in the same way that Cairo does, given that Cairo's image backend uses Pixman, so look at some docs for Cairo. For example, in http://www.cairographics.org/tutorial/ in the section "Drawing with Cairo", subsection "Preparing and Selecting a Source" there is an explanation of linear gradients.

For your 45 degree rotation, I would try the following (one point in the top left corner, the other one in the bottom right one):

```
p1.x = 0; p1.y = 0;
p2.x = width - 1; p2.y = height - 1;
```

P.S.: No, I do not know how gradients with an angle are specified in CSS.

Comment: Right, it really seems to be the same. I have it working now. Thanks a lot!